# Website opening via IP but not domain using AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, nameserver, amazon-route53

I'm using ec2 amazon aws. I have an IP address which is opening the website currently. So I can safely assume my security group is correctly set. I have added the name-server to the domain (godaddy) as well. When I check the whois, the name servers are correct.

However, when I try to open the website using the domain name, it doesn't work. I tried ping domain.com and it returned with "Unknown host".

Please help out as to what I might be missing.

EDIT: This is the domain: --editedout--.com and yes, NS records show the correct Route53 nameservers which suggests DNS is already propagated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using nslookup or better yet the dig utility to query the DNS to see what response your machine is getting but better yet what servers it is getting the response from.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Are you saying you’ve registered the domain at GoDaddy but updated the nameservers so that they are set to Amazon’s route 53? Have you configured route 53 properly to host the domain and the proper records? Have you given sufficient time for the updates to propagate? You could also provide the domain and expected IP address, as neither are secret, and we could check for ourselves what is wrong. Better than playing a guessing game with publicly discoverable  information.

Comment: I've updated the question and added the domain link. Thank You. What is there to configure Route53? I just created a Hosted Zone, added the domain name and copy-paste the 4 name servers. Is there more to it than just this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing A record for your domain in DNS. Please check A record is pointing to IP address of sever.

After you add A record it may take few min to take effect.

Also if you are having more than one site on server then make sure to have entry in httpd.conf file.

Comment: I had added the A records too but it was on the server IP not the elastic IP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  "A" record Or WWW "CNAME" record is not setup for your domain. Login to AWS account and update your hosted zone for the domain. Point A record to your EC2 public IP address. It will take some time to propagate DNS after that.